# Tortoise SVN property substitution - fails for more than one property "group"

Tags: properties, tortoisesvn

I'm using TortoiseSVN 1.6.12, and seeing something very strange behaviour on property substitution. I have some `svn:keyword properties` (configured via TSVN) like this:

`Author, LastChangedBy, Date, DateLastChanged`

which I've applied recursively across every file in the codeset

I then did a simple test on a text file like this

```
Some text
$Author$
$LastChangedBy$
$Date$
$LastChangedDate$
```

When I commit my changes, the `Author` and `LastChangedBy` properties are substituted but not the `Date` or `LastChangedDate` ones. I did some experimenting around combinations and it appears that either the author properties are set, or the date ones (but never both). So it must be doing some validation based on property groups. (In TSVN, you can't simply created another `svn:keywords entry`, you're stuck with one).

Has anyone ever encountered this and/or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is simply based on that SVN only replaces keywords which are known to SVN.
You are using the following list of keywords set:

```
Author, LastChangedBy, Date, DateLastChanged
```

but you have placeholders set in your text file:

```
$Author$
$LastChangedBy$
$Date$
$LastChangedDate$
```

the [known keywords](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html) are the following:

```
  URL, HeadURL           
  Author, LastChangedBy
  Date, LastChangedDate
  Rev, Revision
  LastChangedRevision
  Id
  Header
```

The problem you have that svn:keywords must exactly represents the keywords you would like to replace with values. But be aware that keywords are case sensitive. Furthermore you have defined a keyword "DateLastChanged" which does simply not exist and will of course not be replaced by SVN, cause it's unknown by SVN. On the other hand i assume you have a typo in your svn:keywords contents. may be you can copy&past the output of

```
svn pl . -v filename
```

on command line on that file. One point i missed before have you separated the keywords with a space?

Comment: Thanks, I did some more reading and the properties are actually identical anyway. I assumed date was "date created" and "lastchangeddate" was when the last commit was made. Not the case